# SVG rendering badly in Firefox

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I am working on an infographic with sliding carousel `<li>`s, but the SVG is showing up pixelated in Firefox, even though the bug with SVGs in FF has been resolved, I thought. Can anyone see a fix for this?

URL: http://weaver-wp.weavertest.com/radiation-infographic/

Comment: Just fyi - if you mean the aliasing on the left side... same thing happens in Chrome, so it can't be a Firefox specific bug.  What did you generate the SVG with?

Comment: @esnyder Adobe Illustrator. Is there a better tool I can use to generate the SVG?

Comment: I don't see any SVGs on that page. I just see `canvas`.

Comment: @Jim Blackler it's in the CSS as a background-image to the canvas

Comment: I only see the aliasing on the gray-on-white portions.  Black on white and grey on black appear normal to me.  Did you have a transparency setting?

Comment: @esnyder For me, there's a bit of aliasing, but that's Ok. In Firefox however, the whole image on the left hand side is pixelated really badly. Not sure why...?

Comment: The SVG file is here: http://weaver-wp.weavertest.com/wp-content/themes/weaverdigital/images/radiation-images/radiation-silhouette.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are zooming your SVG file to a very large size:

```css
background-size: 9730px 30000px;
background-position: -7310px -29250px;
```

Most browsers will not antialias very large SVG shapes, as it requires too much graphics memory. (This is what we see in Safari and Chrome.) It looks like Firefox is actually rendering the SVG to the size of the canvas and then blowing it up with image interpolation to your cropped region.

The fix for both is the same:
Crop your SVG first and use just the cropped portion as a background.

Comment: I like this answer.  I hope OP remembers to come back and let us know if it was the solution.

Comment: I'm hesitant to crop the SVG because it took quite a while to work out the co-ordinates for the background postions/zooms. Plus, I'm a bit out of my depth as it is with this SVG stuff. Just to clarify, are you suggesting slicing the SVG up into smaller chunks and piecing them together somehow?

Comment: @Dalogi As far as I could tell you seemed to be using just a small subsection of the SVG as a background image for a canvas. Perhaps if you stepped back and explained the visual effect you were trying to accomplish, and the browsers you need to support, my suggestion might change.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this graphic. The concept of the infographic is that throughout the series of carousel slides, the orange ball represents the amount of radiation against the scaled silhouette (SVG) image of the man. With every slide the silhouette decreases in size, visualising the growth of the radiation ball, until by the last slide the ball is much larger than the man. The sizes of both graphics are to the correct scale, and the positions are such that by the end the man is at the same horizontal line as the ball.

Comment: @Dalogi I see! So why are you using the SVG as a background image to an HTML5 Canvas instead of just embedding the SVG directly?

Comment: @Phrogz I wasn't sure how to go about that correctly, and am a newbie with both HTML5 canvas and SVG. How difficult would this be at this stage, and will the positioning co-ordinates have to be worked out from scratch?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, but I've gone back to basics and used individual jpegs for each slide. Works well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[viewbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)** property of the  element when panning/zoooming. It is much higher performance and simpler to use.